# SEO Friendly Tabs

Tags: seo, google-search

How to add Meta Data explicitly for tabs ? 
I have some pages which have tabs in it which opens URLs of type www.blahblah.com/page#tab1
How to add meta data related to tab1 tab2 etc. I do not want to add it in parent page.

EDIT : [Reference](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170&topic=21997&ctx=topic)

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Person">
   My name is <span itemprop="name">Bob Smith</span>, 
   but people call me <span itemprop="nickname">Smithy</span>.
   Here is my homepage: 
// Does this URL Come up in Search as primary Link ? If so I can set it to 
mysite.com/page#tab1 
   ##<a href="http://www.example.com" itemprop="url">www.example.com</a>.##
   I live in 
   <span itemprop="address" itemscope
      itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Address">
      <span itemprop="locality">Albuquerque</span>, 
      <span itemprop="region">NM</span> 
   </span>
   and work as an <span itemprop="title">engineer</span>
   at <span itemprop="affiliation">ACME Corp</span>.
</div>
```

Comment: If all your tabs content is already loaded on the page, and the other pages is just hidden, you would be best of just give every tab a good heading and just see all tabs as a long document with different sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified by  [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4) the `<meta>`tag can only be located in the `<head>` part of your HTML so you can't use these tags for your tabs. However, you could use [Sitemaps](http://www.sitemaps.org/)
 could be a good solution for you. According to the site,

> Sitemap 0.90 is offered under the terms of the Attribution-ShareAlike Creative Commons License and has wide adoption, including support from Google, Yahoo!, and Microsoft.

You can generate the sitemap of your site with [this site](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/) in XML, add the tabs manually, and then submit it to the different search engines directly or add it in your `robots.txt` file as follows:

```
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap_location.xml
```

You could also use microdata, as specified in this [W3C Specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/md/). According to the spec:

> When a string value is a URLs, it is expressed using the a element and
>   its href attribute, the img element and its src attribute, or other
>   elements that link to or embed external resources.

So even if your URL contains a fragment (the `#` part), the different search engines should point to the correct tab. For example, Google adds a "jump to" link. See this [old blog post](http://seocowboy.co.za/google-announcement/how-google-indexes-named-anchors).

Comment: Ok but I was trying in another approach , edited my question please check it if that can be accomplished

Comment: edited my answer according to your question edit.

Comment: Thanks that blog mentions about jump to links, which might be what i am looking , but couldnt find any documentation on hwo to get them in results all i got is you need old style anchor tag with name and a div id with that name ,http://vincesamios.com/internetmarketing/how-to-get-%E2%80%9Cjump-to%E2%80%9D-links-in-google-search-results#SERPJumpTo http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2009/09/using-named-anchors-to-identify.html

Answer (score 0):

EDIT  : https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification
This explains it all.
Summarizing the article. for all Ajax callbacks server side pages should also be implemented

```
Request

The crawler agrees to request from the server ugly URLs of the format:

domain[:port]/path?_escaped_fragment_=hashfragment
domain[:port]/path?queryparams&_escaped_fragment_=hashfragment
domain[:port]/path?_escaped_fragment_=
domain[:port]/path?queryparams&_escaped_fragment_=
Search result

The search engine agrees to display in the search results the corresponding pretty URLs:

domain[:port]/path#!hashfragment
domain[:port]/path?queryparams#!hashfragment
domain[:port]/path
domain[:port]/path?queryparams
```